# how to integrate rails on eclipse and create a war file and deploy on Apache server in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, apache

i integrate rails on eclipse with below process

```
Go to Help -> Install New Software...
Click add (top right of popup)
Enter a Name like "RadRails2"
Enter the location as http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install
Click ok
```

will processing i facing an issue like

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.etools.common.frameworks,1.0.300.v20160406_2204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.etools.emf.workbench.ui,5.1.500.v20160406_2204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.etools.aries.juno,1.5.100.v20120717_1538
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.ibm.etools.aries.v38.feature,1.5.100.v20120717_1538
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.ibm.etools.j2ee.common,7.0.500.v20160406_2204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.etools.rpe.jetty8,1.0.0.v20120918_0346
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.ibm.etools.rpe.jetty8.feature,1.0.0.v20120918_0346
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.ibm.websphere.wdt.dependency.eclipse43,1.0.0.v20151126_2246
```

how to solve this can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to Help -> Install New Software...
Click add (top right of popup)
Enter a Name like "RadRails2"
Enter the location as http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install
Click ok
```

[image]

in the above pic uncheck the contact all update sites during install to find required software

and proceed forward it install successfully